# vscode deleted my python files after i updated it

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im fairly new to python and ive just lost a month's worth of files. VScode asked me to restart it so it can update, so i did. I've been keeping my actual python files in the same folder as the instalastion folder. Once it restarted my folder with all the files was gone. Is there any way to recover the files ?

Comment: Are you sure it is gone though? Surely it is saved somewhere otherwise you cannot run the python program. Or did you code without running the program for a month?

Comment: they were saved files, i have run them many times. when i try to open them it either says location is not available or it opens them but they are empty.